# Resizing and interpolating middle values in column in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(level = c(1:10), values = c(3,4,5,6,8,9,4,2,1,6))
```

Which I would like to resize to fewer levels, lets say 6 levels.

Where level 0 and level 10 are corresponding to level 0 and level 6 in the new dataframe. (I just guessed some floats in between, not sure what the result would actually be)

```
level   value
    1       3       
    2     3.4
    3     4.6
    4     6.2
    5     2.2
    6       6
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `approxfun` for interpolation like below?

```
data.frame(
  level = 1:6,
  values = approxfun(df$level, df$values)(seq(1, nrow(df), length.out = 6))
)
```

which gives

```
  level values
1     1    3.0
2     2    4.8
3     3    7.2
4     4    7.0
5     5    1.8
6     6    6.0
```